# How to use a reactive variable to subset a df in r? then reshape the new dataframe and place it in renderDT?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I am making a shiny dashboard and I have a dataframe I created with a year column, district column, and columns for several vaccines. I want the user to be able to choose a vaccine from a drop down list. Using the input the code would then create a subset of the dataframe to display. I first need to reshape it before I display it though.

----- This is the UI section

```
fluidRow(
                                            selectInput(inputId = "Immunization", label = "Select group", c("FLU","HEPA","HEPB")),
                                            DTOutput('AdultTable'))
                                        
                                          
                                 ),
```

----- This is the code I have currently in the Server section. When I try to run it, it tells me:

Warning: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext: Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
65: <Anonymous>
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.

```
  vaccine_sel = reactive(input$Immunization)
                         
 requested_table = (requested_table = subset(Imm, select = c("REPORT_YEAR", "DISTRICT_ID", req(vaccine_sel()))))
  

  requested_table = reshape(requested_table, idvar = "DISTRICT_ID", timevar = "REPORT_YEAR", direction = "wide")
  
  
  
  
  output$AdultTable = renderDT(
  

    requested_table, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE, searching = FALSE, pageLength = 15, paging = FALSE, scrollX = TRUE) 
    
  )
```

----- And If I try putting this into a reactive() environment, it still gives me an error:

Warning: Error in reactive: `...` must be empty.
✖ Problematic argument:
• requested*table = subset(Imm, select = c("REPORTYEAR", "DISTRICT*_ID", req(vaccine_sel())))
55: <Anonymous>
Error in reactive(requested_table = subset(Imm, select = c("REPORT_YEAR"
*`...` must be empty.*
*✖ Problematic argument:*
*• requestedtable = subset(Imm, select = c("REPORTYEAR", "DISTRICT_ID*", req(vaccine_sel())))

---- If I hardcode "FLU" into it then it works just fine.

```
requested_table = requested_table = subset(Imm, select = c("REPORT_YEAR", "DISTRICT_ID", "FLU"))
```

---- It will give me the 3 columns I want and then I can reshape from there.

[This is a clip of what the data looks like before the user chooses the disease](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjVCX.png)

[This is what it would hopefully look  like if it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkIKI.png)

Answer (score 0):

> `You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.`

... is a polite hint (OK: error) that you're trying to use a reactive component (in your case: `input$Immunization`) outside a, well, reactive *consumer* like `observe` - without which Shiny wouldn't listen to changes of that component.
You could try along the following lines:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

df <- data.frame(vaccine = gl(2, 4, labels = LETTERS[1:2]),
                 value = rnorm(8)
                 )

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput('vaccine', label = 'choose vaccine', choices = c('A' , 'B')),
    DTOutput('table')
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
        output$table <- renderDT(df |> filter(vaccine == input$vaccine)) 
    }) |> bindEvent(input$vaccine)
}

if (interactive()) shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you! having everything wrapped within observe was helpful